# apt-get error on drone.io

Tags: ubuntu, apt, drone.io

I am having a problem with my build on `drone.io` just running the `apt-get update` command. It errors out with:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Below are my steps in my build:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y zip xsltproc
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
sudo apt-get install elixir
cd /home/ubuntu/src/github.com/lowks/Radpath
rm -rf deps
yes | mix deps.get --all
mix deps.compile
mix test
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the same problem. Looks like `sudo apt-get update` is broken for legacy Ubuntu 12.04.

This one worked for me if called before the update

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej*`

Comment: Thanks! Build has been fixed.

Comment: Too bad, that drone.io discontinued their service.